# How to set up a server system if all you want is on demand "Burst" Bandwidth a few times a year?

Tags: amazon-ec2, bandwidth, server, rackspace-cloud

We are looking for the a good way to set up a server system that is "on call" and will only be used a few (but random) times a year. It needs to be super powerful with high server capacity and super high bandwidth but we'd rather not pay an arm and a leg to have dedicated servers around the clock. Are there options out there in the managed hosting world that could fill that need? We would need to have the ability to activate the system and begin running scripts with very little notice ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. I am assuming that "very little notice" is acceptable if it is in the order of 2-3 minutes (the time it takes to boot-up a machine).

Provision high power server(s) based on your needs. Keep them in the `SHUTDOWN` state (machine powered off). Whenever, you want to make use of the computing power, boot it up and use. You will be charged only for the amount of time that the server is `RUNNING`. Your data and server state would be preserved. The only charges that you would be paying for would be for storage which is extremely low. Here is the [pricing calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) that you can use to estimate your costs.

Comment: This will work well. Looks like they allow you to turn the servers on and off through their API as well. Thanks!